# Is the Conjugate of irrational number unique?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have the number $3+\sqrt {4} $  , what is its conjugate?
  Is it unique?

What about the number  $2\sqrt {3}+3\sqrt {5}$?

I need an explanation or a proof why the conjugate is not unique?

**Note** :The conjugate of an irrational number is a non-zero number such that the product of the two numbers is rational.

Comment: What do you mean by conjugate?

Comment: @Carlos Toscano-Ochoa  The conjugate of an irrational number is a non-zero number such that the product of the two numbers is rational.

Comment: $2\sqrt {3}+3\sqrt {5}$ has conjugate $2\sqrt {3}-3\sqrt {5}$ ... I think the idea is their product will give a rational value.

Comment: @Medo so you mean that a proposed irrational number multiplied by its conjugate, must be equal to a rational number, right?

Comment: @Carlos Toscano-Ochoa  exactly

Comment: @Medo If you define the conjugates to be the other roots of the minimal polynomial, then there will be several of them in general. For example, the minimal polynomial of $2\sqrt{3}+3\sqrt{5}$ is $x^4 - 114 x^2 + 1089 $ and its $4$ roots $\pm 2\sqrt{3} \pm 3\sqrt{5}$ are all conjugates in that sense.

Comment: If $x$ is a conjugate then $kx$ is also a conjugate for rational $k$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  why the question been put "on hold" ; and how to remove it from "on hold " since i make it clear now?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio  same question of Dietrich Burde

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown     same question of Dietrich Burde

Comment: I voted to reopen the question as the OP has added his definition of conjugate.

Comment: Btw, conjugation, according to your definition is not unique. Consider the irrational number $\sqrt{2}$. Then $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2} = 2 \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $\sqrt{2}*\sqrt{8} = \sqrt{16} = 4 \in \mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 4):

Edit: This answers originally addressed the question without the added explanation what *conjugate* meant to the OP.

With the addition, the conjugates of an irrational number $\alpha$ are all numbers $x/\alpha$ with $x \in {\Bbb Q}\setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace$, so definitely not unique.

By the way, strictly speaking, you have not defined what the conjugates of $3 + \sqrt{4} = 5$ are, as your definition only defines the notion of conjugate for irrational numbers. Applying the definition unchanged to rational numbers as well, the answer doesn't change: its conjugates are all elements of ${\Bbb Q}\setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace$.

Also, where does this notation of conjugate come from? I realize this is the definition that is given at [answers.com](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_conjugate_of_an_irrational_number), but the example given there is that conjugates of $a + b\sqrt{x}$ are $a - b\sqrt{x}$ and $-a + b\sqrt{x}$. So, it seems whoever wrote that had a different definition in mind.

---

Original answer

What *conjugate* means, depends on the context. If you're looking at complex numbers vs. real numbers, then conjugate means complex conjugate. All of your three numbers are then their own conjugate.

More generally, you can look at a field extension $\Bbb Q \subseteq L$ and all embeddings $\sigma$ of $L$ in $\mathbb C$. In such a context, the *conjugates* of an element $\alpha \in L$ are then all the images $\sigma(\alpha)$ for these $\sigma$. This is the same as saying that the conjugates of $\alpha$ are the (other) roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

For instance, in your case, look at the extension $\Bbb Q \subseteq \Bbb Q(\sqrt 3, \sqrt 5)$. There are four embeddings of $\sigma \colon \Bbb Q(\sqrt 3, \sqrt 5) \to {\mathbb C}$. One is the identity, one sends $\sqrt 3$ to $-\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt 5$ to itself, one sends $\sqrt 5$ to $-\sqrt 5$ and $\sqrt 3$ to itself, and the last one sends $\sqrt 3$ to $-\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt 5$ to $-\sqrt 5$. The conjugates of $2 \sqrt 3 + 3 \sqrt 5$, in this context, are $-2 \sqrt 3 + 3\sqrt 5$, $2 \sqrt 3 - 3 \sqrt 5$, and $-2 \sqrt 3 - 3 \sqrt 5$. Note, these are the (other) roots of the minimal polynomial $x^4 - 114 ^2 + 1089$ of $2 \sqrt 3 + 3\sqrt 5$. So, an element can have more than one conjugate. Without further context, this is the most likely interpretation of the notion of conjugate.

Furthermore, in any possible context, $3 + \sqrt 4 = 5$ only has itself as conjugate, since every possible embedding must send $5$ to itself. (Or, if you prefer, its minimal polynomial is $x - 5$ and that has only $5$ as a root.)

Even more generally, you can look at a field extension $K \subseteq L$ and all embeddings $\sigma$ of $L$ in an algebraically closed field containing $L$ that leave $K$ fixed. Again, in that context, the images $\sigma(\alpha)$ of an element $\alpha \in L$ are called its conjugates.

In your case, you could look at the extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3) \subseteq \Bbb(\sqrt 3, \sqrt 5)$. From this point of view, $2\sqrt 3 + 3\sqrt 5$ only has a single conjugate, namely $2 \sqrt 3 - 3\sqrt 5$.